# how to show hide fields and show when value is selected from dropdownlist and pressed a button

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried to make a  PHP result with fields like `first name`, `last name`, `gender` with radio button, category as dropdown list having fields basic and advance having subjects like  `english`, `science`, `maths` ,`general knowledge` all having input `type=text` to fill the marks and beside category dropdownlist there is a button name get.

So if we select basic and press get button then it should display `english` and `general knowledge` same if we select advance and press get button should display `maths` and `science`.

Now if we enter submit button then it should jump to next page and should have category as dropdownlist if we select  advance then it should display students with data stored in table in phpmysq. So I don't know how to hide and display subjects until we select advance or basic field and display only the specific subjects using  PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you're struggling with including what you've already tried. As is your question seems a bit broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*pg 1 named = insert_result.php*/

> First Name:
>     ">
>   
>   
>   
>     Last Name:
>     ">
>   
>   
>   
>     Gender:
>     />male
>     />female
>   
>   
>   
>     Category:
>     
>     
>      select
>      >basic
>      >advanced 
>     
>     
>     
>   
>   
>   
>   
>     Gujarati:
>     
>   
>   
>     Hindi:
>     
>   
>   
>   
>   
>     English:
>     
>   
>   
>   
>     Science:

/*this is for pg 1 
and now for pg 2

pg 2 named display_result.php*/

> **Category:**
>         
>             select
>             basic
>             advanced
>         
>         
>         Back
>   
>    
>   
>   
>     
>   
>     
>         First Name:
>         
>     
>     
>         Last Name:
>         
>     
>     
>         Gender:
>         
>     
>     
>         Category
>
> ```
>   <?php
>   if($_POST['cat']=="basic")
>   {
>   ?>
> ```
>
> Gujarati:
>         
>     
>     
>         Hindi:
>         
>     
>     
>   
>     English:
>         
>     
>     
>         Science:

/*and at last made a data table in phpmysql with all fields and named as result*/

Comment: to view, the full answer just select edit field beside of share

Answer (score 0):

you can **set cookie** once if it select any option, according to the cookie value you can hide and show the content next page,

try this format in java script

//on change or on select of input

```
document.cookie = "key1=value1;expires=date";
```

// in next page you can check the value of the cookie is exist something like

```
var key1exist = getCookie("key1");
    if (key1exist == "abcd") 
    {
        // do the stuff
    }
```